# Getting text between PHP code blocks

Tags: php, regex

I want to make RegEXP to get text between php code blocks

for exsample i have this code and i want to get TEXT 1 and TEXT2

```
 <?php some code ?> TEXT1 <?php some code {?> TEXT2 <?php }some code?>
```

Comment: Where is the text in TEXT1 and TEXT2 coming from?

Comment: @netcoder I forgot to write that text1 may be html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [tokenizer](http://php.net/token_get_all) instead of regular expressions:

```
$input = '<?php some code ?> TEXT1 <?php some code {?> TEXT2 <?php }some code?>';

$tokens = token_get_all($input);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
   if ($token[0] == T_INLINE_HTML) {
       echo $token[1];
   }
}
```

Output:

```
 TEXT1  TEXT2
```

Comment: I forgot to write that text1 may be html

Comment: @Ortal: If it's HTML and you just want the text (without the tags), just use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) on the value afterwards. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as you can use file_get_contents() on the php file and it will return the raw contents without parsing the PHP.  As for the regex, I'd recommend the regex cheatsheet by dave child at addedbytes.com.  http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/  That should help you piece together a regex for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe something like

> (?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)